# How to send an ajax request in the angular 6?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, request

I am completely unfamiliar with the `angular` since I am a `back-end` developer. To test my `api`, I need to send an ajax request from `angular`.
Tell me how to do this?
There is a code. The request must be executed before clearing the `localeStorage`.

```
<button (click)="logoutAndClose()" class="btn_green btn_ml" mat-raised-button>
  Log out
</button>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logout-modal',
  templateUrl: './logout-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout-modal.component.scss']
})
export class LogoutModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<LogoutModalComponent>,
              private router: Router,
              private http: HttpClient,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  logoutAndClose(): void {
    this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/users/settings/logout/")
    localStorage.clear();
    this.thisDialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigateByUrl(RouteUrls.Login);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use angular's http client https://angular.io/guide/http . Http client works with `Observable`, if you don't know what these are, I suggest you to take the angular tour.

Comment: You just need to subscribe your post request, until no requests will go to the endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice you should create a service to send HTTP requests:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  private url: string = "http://api";
  private endpoint:string = "car";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
             ) { }


  get(id: number): Observable<Car> {
      return this.httpClient
          .get<Car>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
          .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
}
```

and then you will be available to use built in dependency injection in your component:

```
export class YourCarComponent {
    constructor(private yourService: YourService) {
    }

    getCars(id: number) {
       this.yourService.get(id)
           .subscribe(s=> console.log(s));
}
```

UPDATE:

In order to execute your http query, you need to run it. So you need to call `subscribe` method:

```
this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/users/settings/logout/")
         .subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```

In addition, as a best practice should not contain an implementation details of http requests because it is not deal of view. View should just show data.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to import the HTTPModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
```

2. Inject inside constructor:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

3. 

```
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: CanBeDirectlyMapToJsonObject) => {});
```

For More details refer to https://angular.io/guide/http